# Python mysql.connector rowcount > 0 but fetchall() shows no results

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql.connector and running:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

def get_db_connection(user, password, database):
        try:
            return mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password,
                                           host='localhost',
                                           database=database)

        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exist")
            else:
                print(err)
        else:
            cnx.close()

    db = get_db_connection('user', 'password', 'database123')

    cursor = db.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM companies;"

    cursor.execute(query)

    companies_results = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm getting the "mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from." error yet the row count > 0 (it's 2). I know there are just 2 results in that table.

System details:
- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.0
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.3-MariaDB

Comment: What happens if you don't do the rowcount and just call fetchall?

Comment: Same thing unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, only thing I can think of is some compatibility thing in the library. Assuming you install this all through pip? Perhaps try using conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I htought I had Fixed this by adding the `buffered` parameter to the cursor.

```
cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
```

THIS IS NOT TRUE.

I realised as I was debugging I had a watch variable on cursor.fetchall(). This was running the command ahead of when it being called in the code, meaning by the time it reached the code there we no results to be fetched.

Solution: Do not have watch variables of cursor.fetchall()